# Selenium with python (select option)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am testing selenium with python and I need to select an option from a dropdown.

In this case I am testing with a website https://www.motogp.com/es/gp-results/2024/qat/motogp/rac/classification, I need to change the rac option to any other spr for example, since when changing it directly on the web redirects to rac.

I have tried:

```
select_element = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "primary-filter__filter-select--cat")
select = Select(select_element)
```

However, I can't select the option.  I would like to get the url correctly.

Comment: Care, your XPATH class name  doesnt match "primary-filter__filter-select--cat", full match is "primary-filter__filter-select primary-filter__filter-select--cat" and match 2 elements.

Answer (score 1):

**Issue** is in this code: `By.CLASS_NAME, "primary-filter__filter-select--cat"`. It won't locate any web element.

**Solution:** Use XPath locator strategy as below

```
By.XPATH, "(//select[@class='primary-filter__filter-select primary-filter__filter-select--cat'])[2]"
```

**XPath expression explanation:**

- `(//select[@class='primary-filter__filter-select primary-filter__filter-select--cat'])[2]` -- locates the second dropdown list element (`<select>`) with the specified class attribute value `primary-filter__filter-select primary-filter__filter-select--cat` within the HTML document

**Here is the full working code:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get("https://www.motogp.com/es/gp-results/2024/qat/motogp/rac/classification")

# Click on Rechazar button
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "onetrust-reject-all-handler"))).click()

select_element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//select[@class='primary-filter__filter-select primary-filter__filter-select--cat'])[2]")))
select = Select(select_element)
select.select_by_visible_text("SPR")
time.sleep(20)
```

**Result:**

[image]